# re-render behaves differently between Chrome's built-in "paint flashing" and Chrome's react dev tools' "highlight updates"

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

re-rendering area differs in chrome's paint flashing from chrome's react dev tools' highlight updates.

Only alarm number should be highlighted.

[[image: chrome's paint flashing[1]]

[image: chrome's react dev tools' highlight updates]

Comment: Which GIF is from Chrome DevTools which one is from React?

Comment: top is from chrome, bottom is from react @KayceBasques